# jest updateSnapshot for specific test file

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to figure out how o update a single snapshot file. In the docs it says just add the -t and I presume the file name but thats not working for me.

Example, in terminal I use.

```
jest -u -t test/js/tests/components/myTestApp.test.js
```

Any ideas why this would not work. I also added it as a string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to doc https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html `-t` option is searching not for file name, but for specific spec name. They provided an example

```
jest -u -t="ColorPicker"
```

where "ColorPicker" is name of the spec, given in `describe` or `test` blocks.

Comment: So, do I NEED to install jest-cli globally? Because it says "The term 'jest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet..." ?

Comment: @Cubelaster you don't have to install jest globally as you could pre-pend it with `npx` (i.e. `npx jest -u -t="ColorPicker"`) to call the local instance of the package.

Answer (score 20):

In order to update particular snapshot, you can pass name as an argument to your script `test` command.

**In package.json**

```
"test": "jest --verbose"
```

**In command line**

```
npm test "<spec name>" -- -u
```

OR

```
npm test "<spec name>" -- --updateSnapshot
```

Comment: thanks! both command line commands worked for me and I didn't have to install jest globally!

Answer (score 17):

this works

```
jest /path/to/file --updateSnapshot
```

Answer (score 6):

If you run Jest via `npm test`, you can use arguments by inserting a `--` between `npm test` and the Jest arguments - path & snapshot flag:

`npm test -- path/to/file -u`